# how to add a scrollbar in this code without using canvas and without making a object of root

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I hsve given the full code out here plsss tell me in this code how to add a scrollbar

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as msg``
from pymysql import *
class TY(Frame):
    def __init__(self,ghj):
        super().__init__(ghj)
          conn=connect(db='future',user='root',passwd='1234',host='localhost')
    cur=conn.cursor()
    i=cur.execute("select max(sid) from data")
    rs=cur.fetchall()
    self.txt56=Label(self,text="Name |",font=("Copperplate Gothic Bold",20,'bold'))
    self.txt556=Label(self,text="ConsultantName |",font=("Copperplate Gothic Bold",20,'bold'))
    self.txt516=Label(self,text="Mobile Number |",font=("Copperplate Gothic Bold",20,'bold'))
    self.txt526=Label(self,text="Date Of Joining |",font=("Copperplate Gothic Bold",20,'bold'))
    self.txt536=Label(self,text="Company |",font=("Copperplate Gothic Bold",20,'bold'))
    self.txt546=Label(self,text="Status |",font=("Copperplate Gothic Bold",20,'bold'))
    self.txt547=Label(self,text="Package |",font=("Copperplate Gothic Bold",20,'bold')) 
    self.txt56.grid(row=0,column=0)
    self.txt556.grid(row=0,column=1)
    self.txt516.grid(row=0,column=2)
    self.txt526.grid(row=0,column=3)
    self.txt536.grid(row=0,column=4)
    self.txt546.grid(row=0,column=5)
    self.txt547.grid(row=0,column=6)
    self.pack()
    a=rs[0][0]
    j=cur.execute("select * from data")
    bs=cur.fetchall()
    for x in range(a+1):
        for y in range(7):
            self.text33=Label(self,text=bs[x][y],font=("Javanese Text",20))
            self.text33.grid(row=x+1,column=y)
    self.pack()

ob8=Tk()
st6=TY(ob8)
ob8.mainloop()
```

plss tell me how to add the scollbar without channging anthing like whithout adding a  canvas method or making a text box or a list box just tell me the way i can add it intoo this

Answer (score 0):

> plss tell me how to add the scollbar without channging anthing like whithout adding a canvas method or making a text box or a list box just tell me the way i can add it intoo this

Given those constraints, you can't do what you want. A normal window or frame is not scrollable.

If you need to scroll a group of widgets, your only practical choice is to use a canvas or text widget as the container. If you don't need to use a widget such as a label, your other choice is to use a listbox or treeview.